# Show convergence of infinite product

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

Let $w \in \mathbb{C}$ be a complex number with $0 <|w|<1$. Show that the infinite product 
$$\theta(z) := \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+w^{2n-1}e^z)(1+w^{2n-1}e^{-z})$$
converges locally uniformly and absolutely for $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

We have a theorem that states that for a sequence of holomorphic functions $f_n$, if the infinite series of $[f_n(z)-1]$ converges absolutely and locally uniformly, then the infinite product of $f_n(z)$ converges absolutely and locally uniformly. I believe we can use this and solve the question by proving the convergence of the corresponding infinite series using the Weierstrass M-test, but I cannot seem to bound the series from above. Or how should I do this?

Comment: Could you use the [Jacobi triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product) which relates it to an infinite sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your series is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\big|w^{2n-1}e^z\big|+\big|w^{2n-1}e^{-z}\big|\right)
$$
For $|w|<1$  a fixed number and $z$ in a bounded set, this should be easy to bound.

---

Suppose $z$ is in the set $\{z : |z| \le M\}$.  Then
$|e^z| = e^{\operatorname{Re} z} \le e^M$ and
$|e^{-z}| = e^{-\operatorname{Re} z} \le e^M$, so

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\big|w^{2n-1}e^z\big|+\big|w^{2n-1}e^{-z}\big|\right)
\le
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(|w|^{2n-1}e^M+|w|^{2n-1}e^{M}\right)
= \frac{2e^M |w|}{1-|w|^2} .
$$
Therefore, by the Weierstrass M-test, the infinite series converges uniformly on the set $\{z : |z|\le M\}$.  And so $\theta(z)$ converges uniformly and absolutely on $\{z : |z| \le M\}$.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, a term $w^{4n-2}$ is missing.

Comment: Corrected.  Two terms in the sum correspond to two factors in the product.

Comment: I can't seem to see how it bounds? Let's say we look in $B(0,1)$, then $|w^{2n-1}e^{±z}| \leq |e^{±z}| \leq e$, won't each term be bounded by the constant $e$, so that the series doesn't converge?

Comment: Why isn't the last equality given by $\frac{2e^M}{ |w|} \cdot \frac{1}{1-|w|^2}$?

Comment: The sum is from $n=1$ to $\infty$, not $n=0$ to $\infty$.